# What permissions are required in SQL Server for tableau user to access db functions

Tags: sql, tableau-api, sql-server-2017, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to set up a Tableau user to run custom queries (some of which may contain function calls) but public (server role) and `db_datareader` (user mapping) doesn't seem to cut it.

I assigned `db_owner` temporarily because I'm the only one with access currently but that is not a long term solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Bob

Comment: Create role and explicitly grant all the privileges you need. What the answer do you expect except some "superuser" role?

Comment: @astentx, I am looking for the specific privileges that are needed to be able to run queries on tables if those queries include functions or stored procedures.  When I added the user to the db_datareader role, it returned an error that indicated permissions were insufficient to execute the function.